# Django REST Framework - Social Authentication (Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I'm building REST APIs for a platform where we have iOS, Android and Web apps as clients. Users can register normally via the Django APIs, so authenticate using their credentials or they can sign in to their Facebook or Twitter account using OAuth.

I started using [`django-rest-framework-social-oauth2`](https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2) to speed up the development of the social login part.
The part that I don't understand is related to the *URL callback* (or *URL redirect*) pointing back to the server-side Django app.

What URL callback should I provide? Is there already an implemented view out-of-the-box from `django-rest-framework-social-oauth2`?

Also, is there a better package available for DRF to be used for the authentication of big projects?

Answer (score 3):

The new way of doing that is by using python-social-auth, as django-social-auth was deprecated in favor of python-social-auth and now supports other frameworks than Django such as Flask, Pyramid, Web.py and Tornado.

It also supports other major auth providers such as Microsoft, Google, Twitter, Amazon, GitHub and many more.

### Summary;

- https://github.com/mlavin/django-all-access
- https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth
- https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth
- https://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth
- https://github.com/hiidef/oauth2app
- https://github.com/timetric/django-oauth
- https://github.com/daaku/django-oauth-consumer
- https://github.com/eldarion/django-oauth-access
- https://github.com/dgouldin/python-oauth2
- https://github.com/henriklied/django-twitter-oauth
- https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth
- https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/oauth/
- http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/

---

### [django-all-access](https://github.com/mlavin/django-all-access)

---

django-all-access is a reusable application for user registration and authentication from OAuth 1.0 and OAuth 2.0 providers such as Twitter and Facebook.

The goal of this project is to make it easy to create your own workflows for authenticating with these remote APIs. django-all-access will provide the simple views with sane defaults along with hooks to override the default behavior.

*There is a simple demo application running on at http://allaccess-mlavin.dotcloud.com/ The full source of this application is include in the repository.*

### [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth)

---

Integrated set of Django applications addressing authentication, registration, account management as well as 3rd party (social) account authentication.

#### Supported Flows

- Signup of both local and social accounts
- Connecting more than one social account to a local account
- Disconnecting a social account -- requires setting a password if only the local account remains
- Optional instant-signup for social accounts -- no questions asked
- E-mail address management (multiple e-mail addresses, setting a primary)
- Password forgotten flow
- E-mail address verification flow

#### Supported Providers

- Dropbox (OAuth)
- Facebook (both OAuth2 and JS SDK)
- Github
- Google (OAuth2)
- LinkedIn
- OpenId
- Persona
- SoundCloud (OAuth2)
- Stack Exchange (OAuth2)
- Twitch (OAuth2)
- Twitter
- Weibo (OAuth2)

### [Django Social Auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)

---

Django Social Auth is an easy way to setup social authentication/authorization mechanism for Django projects.

Crafted using base code from [django-twitter-oauth](https://github.com/henriklied/django-twitter-oauth) and [django-openid-auth](https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth), it implements a common interface to define new authentication providers from third parties.

#### Supported Providers

- Google OpenID
- Google OAuth
- Google OAuth2
- Yahoo OpenID
- OpenId like myOpenID
- Twitter OAuth
- Facebook OAuth

### [Django-Socialauth](https://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth)

---

#### What it does

1. Allow logging in via various providers.
2. Import contacts from various third party sites, to find out which of your
   friends already use our service.

#### Logging In

This is a application to enable authentication via various third party sites.
In particular it allows logging in via

- Twitter
- Gmail
- Facebook
- Yahoo(Essentially openid)
- OpenId

### [oauth2app](https://github.com/hiidef/oauth2app)

---

The oauth2app module helps Django site operators provide an OAuth 2.0 interface. The module is registered as an application.

### [django-oauth](https://github.com/timetric/django-oauth)

---

This is a forked version of David Larlet's django-oauth.

One very important difference is that this version requires that you be running a real cache behind [Django's caching framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/).

### django-oauth-access

---

#### [Supported Providers](https://github.com/eldarion/django-oauth-access)

- Twitter
- LinkedIn
- Yahoo
- Facebook (using OAuth 2.0 — it is functional, but needs more work)
- Likely any OAuth 1.0a compliant site

### [django-oauth-consumer](https://github.com/daaku/django-oauth-consumer)

---

A django application providing infrastructure for consuming OAuth services. It is not for providing OAuth services.

---

Also useful:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#auth
- https://github.com/dgouldin/python-oauth2
- https://github.com/henriklied/django-twitter-oauth
- https://launchpad.net/django-openid-auth
- https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/oauth/
- http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/examples/django-simple.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll go over your list to have a better understanding. The library that I'm using `django-rest-framework-social-oauth2` relies on `python-social-auth`. Do you think is not a good package?

Comment: Also, what URL callback/redirect should be provided to Facebook/Twitter?

Comment: Urls.py  url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')), Let’s set the default values for the LOGIN_URL, LOGOUT_URL and the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL. The LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL will be used to redirect the user after authenticating from Django Login and Social Auth.

LOGIN_URL = 'login' LOGOUT_URL = 'logout' LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

Comment: Call back in facebook would be https://example.com/oauth/complete/facebook/